# How to show data on the view using C# and Angular js

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs

I have the following controller:

```
  public class UserController : BaseApiController
    {
        // GET api/<controller>
        public string Get()
        {
            var currentuser = CurrentUser.Name;
            return currentuser;
        }

    }
```

The value of currentuser I pass it the datacontext in this way:

```
 function getName() {
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                var promise = deferred.promise;
                cachedPromises.currentuser = promise;
                $http.get(baseUrl + 'api/user').success(getSucceeded).error(getFailed);
                return cachedPromises.currentuser;

                function getSucceeded(data) {
                    console.log('data:', data);
                }

                function getFailed(parameters) {
                        console.log("failed", parameters);
                    }
            }
```

On the console log  `console.log('data:', data);` I get the value and in order to apply binding I have to pass this value to the scope in the controller.js. In order to do that, I have done a controller in this way.

```
LogName.$inject = ['$scope', 'datacontext']
    function LogName($scope, datacontext) {

        $scope.name =[];

        datacontext.getName().then(function (currentuser) {
            $scope.name = currentuser;

        });
    }
```

And on the view I have the following code for data binding :

```
 <h1 ng-controller="LogName" class="title">{{name}}</h1>
```

The binding is shown as an empty array, and I don't understand what goes wrong .

EDIT: 
When I do a console log on the controller:

```
  datacontext.getName().then(function (currentuser) {
            $scope.name = currentuser;
            console.log('current', currentuser);

        });
```

Nothing appears on the view, the compiler does not reach the datacontext.getName

Comment: `cachedPromises.currentuser = promise;` This sets the promise as `currentuser`, which later you're trying to bind to. Where are you retrieving the actual value of `currentuser` from?

Comment: function getSucceeded(data) {
                    console.log('data:', data);
                } 

Here I get the value and then I retrieve it in the controller

Comment: even if I change the  datacontext.getName().then(function (currentuser) {
            $scope.name = currentuser; 
to
 datacontext.getName().then(function (data) {
            $scope.name = data;
I get the same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You MVC controller returning string `public string Get()` and you declare  `$scope.name =[];` as array change it to `$scope.name ='';` that should helps

and change your function getName to :

```
function getName() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();


    $http.get(baseUrl + 'api/user').success(getSucceeded).error(getFailed);
     return deffered.promise;

    function getSucceeded(data) {
        console.log('data:', data);
        //add this
        deferred.resolve(data);
    }

    function getFailed(parameters) {
        console.log("failed", parameters);
        deferred.reject(parameters);;
    }
     return deffered.promise;
}
```

Comment: Nothing appears in the view. I am guessing is an empty string

Comment: When I do a  console.log($scope.name); under the controller :
datacontext.getName().then(function (data) {
            $scope.name = data;
console.log($scope.name);
Nothing appears on the screen

Answer (score 1):

You are never resolving your promise to provide the name.  Add a resolve to the getSucceeded function and a reject to the error function.

```
function getSucceeded(data) {
   console.log('data:', data);
   promise.resolve(data);
}

function getFailed(parameters) {
   console.log("failed", parameters);
   promise.reject(parameters);
}
```

This will provide the data to the functions that are waiting on the promise results.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues:

Firstly, you are not resolving the promise. You need to resolve your promise with your data that is returned from the server.

Second, the result is actually in the `results` property of the data that is returned from the server. Here as you are retrieving only name, you should use below code:

```
function getSucceeded(data) {
   console.log('data:', data);
   deferred.resolve(data.results[0]);
}
```

Comment: Its correct approach just that data.result[0], 0  is undefined. So only data would be correct. Thank you

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by "0 is undefined". Can you please elaborate.

Comment: Since I return only one string, I added $scope.name =' '; 
And data. result[0] is not an array, but data = result -> a string

Comment: Not appropriate. Try debugging the script and you will get to know what I am trying to explain.